# Bar chart in Javascript: stacked bars + grouped bars

Tags: charts, javascript

I'm looking for a Javascript solution to mix Grouped and Stacked Bars with a beautiful graph, such as those provided by [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/).

For example if I want to compare downloads on Apple (iPads+iPhones) devices to Android devices, I might have (excuse my terrible ascii art)

```
60k |             ^
50k |    #    ^   ^
40k |#   #    ^  #^
30k |@   #^   ^  #^
20k |@^  #^  #^  @^
10k |@^  @^  @^  @^
   =================
    Jan Feb Mar Apr

Legend
#: iPad Downloads
@: iPhone Downloads
^: Android Downloads
```

Comment: hey @ewalk could you find any solution for that Stacked+Grouped Bar chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html) and [Google Visualization](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html)

for instance you can specify the following:

[image]

```
cht=bvs
chco=4D89F9,C6D9FD
chd=t:10,50,60,80,40|
  50,60,100,40,20
chds=0,160
```

let's say if you change the chd to

[image]

```
cht=bvs
chs=250x150
chco=4D89F9,C6D9FD
chd=t:0,50,0,80,0, 10, 50, 40
      60,0,100,0,20, 50, 100, 60
chds=0,160
```

Take a look at the chart above (as if its a group chart, but actually its stacked).  Then you can append data after to create stacked 'looking' group as the graph is intended.

Answer (score 5):

Hey I just developed grouped+stacked bar chart on d3.js.

- [Source](https://github.com/gencay/stackedGroupedChart)
- [Demo](http://bl.ocks.org/4629518)

Answer (score 3):

Since no one's mentioned [C3.js](http://c3js.org/) yet, here it is, with a stacked+grouped demo ([source](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html))

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#chart",
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', -30, 200, 200, 400, -150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, -100, 200, -150, 50],
            ['data3', -230, 200, 200, -300, 250, 250]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2']
        ]
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [{value:0}]
        }
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.groups([['data1', 'data2', 'data3']])
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [['data4', 100, -50, 150, 200, -300, -100]]
    });
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.groups([['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']])
}, 3000);
```

```css
/*-- Chart --*/
/*-- From https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/blob/0.4.10/c3.css --*/
/*-- Chart --*/
.c3 svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif; }

.c3 path, .c3 line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000; }

.c3 text {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; }

.c3-legend-item-tile, .c3-xgrid-focus, .c3-ygrid, .c3-event-rect, .c3-bars path {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges; }

.c3-chart-arc path {
  stroke: #fff; }

.c3-chart-arc text {
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 13px; }

/*-- Axis --*/
/*-- Grid --*/
.c3-grid line {
  stroke: #aaa; }

.c3-grid text {
  fill: #aaa; }

.c3-xgrid, .c3-ygrid {
  stroke-dasharray: 3 3; }

/*-- Text on Chart --*/
.c3-text.c3-empty {
  fill: #808080;
  font-size: 2em; }

/*-- Line --*/
.c3-line {
  stroke-width: 1px; }

/*-- Point --*/
.c3-circle._expanded_ {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: white; }

.c3-selected-circle {
  fill: white;
  stroke-width: 2px; }

/*-- Bar --*/
.c3-bar {
  stroke-width: 0; }

.c3-bar._expanded_ {
  fill-opacity: 0.75; }

/*-- Focus --*/
.c3-target.c3-focused {
  opacity: 1; }

.c3-target.c3-focused path.c3-line, .c3-target.c3-focused path.c3-step {
  stroke-width: 2px; }

.c3-target.c3-defocused {
  opacity: 0.3 !important; }

/*-- Region --*/
.c3-region {
  fill: steelblue;
  fill-opacity: 0.1; }

/*-- Brush --*/
.c3-brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: 0.1; }

/*-- Select - Drag --*/
/*-- Legend --*/
.c3-legend-item {
  font-size: 12px; }

.c3-legend-item-hidden {
  opacity: 0.15; }

.c3-legend-background {
  opacity: 0.75;
  fill: white;
  stroke: lightgray;
  stroke-width: 1; }

/*-- Tooltip --*/
.c3-tooltip-container {
  z-index: 10; }

.c3-tooltip {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  empty-cells: show;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px -9px #777777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px -9px #777777;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px -9px #777777;
  opacity: 0.9; }

.c3-tooltip tr {
  border: 1px solid #CCC; }

.c3-tooltip th {
  background-color: #aaa;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFF; }

.c3-tooltip td {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px dotted #999; }

.c3-tooltip td > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 6px; }

.c3-tooltip td.value {
  text-align: right; }

/*-- Area --*/
.c3-area {
  stroke-width: 0;
  opacity: 0.2; }

/*-- Arc --*/
.c3-chart-arcs-title {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  font-size: 1.3em; }

.c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-background {
  fill: #e0e0e0;
  stroke: none; }

.c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-gauge-unit {
  fill: #000;
  font-size: 16px; }

.c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-gauge-max {
  fill: #777; }

.c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-gauge-min {
  fill: #777; }

.c3-chart-arc .c3-gauge-value {
  fill: #000;
  /*  font-size: 28px !important;*/ }
```

```html
<!-- link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/masayuki0812/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/masayuki0812/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See also the Dojo toolkit's Dojox Charting API: [Dojox charting](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/charting/)

Comment: This looks like a powerful charting tools but you can either make clusters (I was using the term groups before) or stacks, but not both as far as I can tell.

Comment: From the link, I see: Bars:
Bars - Horizontal bars.
ClusteredBars - Horizontal bars with clustered data sets. Uses Bars.
StackedBars - Stacked data sets with horizontal bars. Uses Bars.